# URL-compatible and easy to parse date-time format?

Tags: java, rest, date, datetime, playframework-2.0

Using Play 2 I want to create a REST API, which shall include

```
/resource/<startDateTime>
```

meaning return all items of resource with a `startDateTime` greater than the startDateTime given in the URL.

So now I need some DateTime format, that can be passed by an URL in a human-readable format and is still easy to parse into a Java Date object inside my Play 2 controller. Any hints / best practices on that? Thanks for any hint!

Update:
Even better would be if Play would do the parsing for me. For java.util.Date in the routes configuration I am getting the error

```
 No QueryString binder found for type java.util.Date. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.
```

Is there anything predefined to parse a Date?

**Update:**

Expected input:
Could be e.g.

```
http://site.com/resource/20121231-141557 # 2012/12/31 14:15:57
```

or sth. else, easy readable - I don't care as long as it can be transfered using an URL and is easy to parse into a Date object.

Comment: Check this [post out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716763/how-do-i-control-the-formatting-of-dates-in-a-url-with-play)

Comment: @bonCodigo: I am looking for the opposite: Given a URL, parse the date in it.

Comment: can you show us your input and expected output?

Comment: added an update to my post. basically I just expect something that can be appended to an url without problems and is easy to read for humans and reasy to parse in java. [updated the Update ;-)]

Answer (score 1):

There is an ISO standard for dates, number 8601.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Date and time values are organized from the most to the least significant: year, month (or week), day, hour, minute, second, and fraction of second.

Comment: didn't know that yet, but I am wondering if Play has already something build in for that

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have two questions here:

1. How to format and parse dates easily? I think the best library for handling dates in java is [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It has methods for formatting and parsing dates in different formats.
2. How to define a route with a custom parser? For that, you need to define your own QueryStringBindable. Look at [this answer about Doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286725/how-to-bind-double-parameter-with-play-2-0-routing/10307927#10307927) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can check native Play2 Path binders here :  https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Binders.scala#L251

Currently, there is nothing to handle Date in parameters.

But you can write your own PathBinder on top of DateTime (JodaTime), with the **ISO 8601** format (use [ISODateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html))

I think it will be a good Pull request ;)